# System.XML.XmlException: ' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

Tags: c#, xml, exception, linq-to-xml

I have an HTML form that i'm trying to load using XDocument.Load, and i'm receiving the following error:

```
' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1257, position 66.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
```

The code is just calling the following:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(pageData.Stream);
```

pageData is a custom object from another system, that is spitting out a datastream. I've had it export the xml back out to a string, and it looks fine.

When i check that line on the HTML, it's just a closing tag for an element. How reliable is the line/position given by the xml exception? I'm just dumping the source of the form into notepad++ for validation, and i can't see that it would be an issue.

EDIT:
The following is the first few lines before and after the error. I've marked the error line.

```
                                        </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>  <----Error Line
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="BusinessJustificationForm">
                    <table id="BusinessJustificationTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="seperator" colspan="7">
```

Comment: from experience its *fairly* accurate, possibly a line or two before/after

Comment: Seems like you have given some space

Comment: I've posted 3 lines above and below the line that is prompting the error and marked the error line above..

Comment: Do you have any html entities?

Comment: using divs in td is not a good idea...

Comment: Daniel, I don't have any entities.

@kul_mi Unfortunately, I inherited a legacy project, and at this point, i'm just trying to dam the holes in a sinking ship.

Comment: @StephenDubya could you please insert some more code? I think there is an entity that is not followed by a semicolon.

Comment: I added more. Please ignore the ugly HTML....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was caused by a "Name" attribute having a name containing spaces. Once i went through the whole thing and resolved that, I was able to load the HTML as an XML document.

Answer (score 21):

The issue I had turned out to be an ampersand `&` in a URL where a semi-colon `;` did not follow it.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.something.com?id=123&name=456"></a>
```

Fortunately the URL did not need to have the ampersand bit in my HTML code so I removed it altogether. I guess URL encoding would help, replacing it to `&amp;` if it was needed.

Answer (score 8):

HTML is different from XML. XML has much more strict rules than HTML. Probably your HTML is not well-formed XML. Unless you can ensure that your HTML is XHTML compliant, you can not parse HTML with an XML parser. Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can check you document in the w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to look at,
XML does not allow HTML attributes without its value.

e.g.;

```
<input required name="Entity" />
```

can't be loaded as XML document and will raise an error as:

> 'name' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='.

Hence better to use:

```
<input required="required" name="Entity" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is mostly descriptive that your attribute having a name containing spaces and it is not allowed as per XMLparser. You need to remove it to meet xml standards. you should use HTML agility pack [http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ ] instead.

Comment: -1: This is just repeating (nearly a year later) what the OP and one of the other answers already stated.