# Convert Xml Api string to Json string UWP

Tags: c#, json, api, xaml, uwp

I used a spoonacular Api via RapidApi. Using the get request I arrived at the xml response string. But when loading the xml string in an xmlDocument an error is returned (I tried to correct that error but others are displayed).

MainPaige.xaml.cs:

```
private void BtnConvertToJson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpResponse<string> response = Unirest.get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/food/products/176011/nutritionWidget")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "f98d566ba1mshd91ae3d16b704c1p183143jsn04deadcdc19b")
    .header("Accept", "text/html")
    .asString();


    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string XamlString = "<div itemprop=\"nutrition\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/NutritionInformation\"><div class=\"spoonacular-caption\">Quickview</div><div class=\"spoonacular-quickview\" itemprop=\"calories\">352 Calories</div><div class=\"spoonacular-quickview\" itemprop=\"proteinContent\">48g Protein</div><div class=\"spoonacular-quickview\" itemprop=\"fatContent\">15g Total Fat</div><div class=\"spoonacular-quickview\" itemprop=\"carbohydrateContent\">0.0g Carbs</div></div><div class=\"spoonacular-caption spoonacular-salmon\">Limit These</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Calories</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">352</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:17.6%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'ENERGY')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('ENERGY')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">18%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Fat</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">15g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:24.22%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'FAT')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('FAT')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">24%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Saturated Fat</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">5g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:34.73%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'FAT_SATURATED')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('FAT_SATURATED')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">35%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Trans Fat</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">0.14g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:100.0%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'FAT_TRANS')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('FAT_TRANS')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">100%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Carbohydrates</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">0.0g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:0.0%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'CARBOHYDRATES')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('CARBOHYDRATES')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">0%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sugar</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">0.0g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:0.0%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'SUGAR')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('SUGAR')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">0%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Cholesterol</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">152mg</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:50.67%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'CHOLESTEROL')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('CHOLESTEROL')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">51%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Sodium</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">109mg</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\" style=\"width:4.74%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'SODIUM')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('SODIUM')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-salmon\">5%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-caption spoonacular-blue\">Get Enough Of These</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Protein</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">48g</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-blue\" style=\"width:97.76%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'PROTEIN')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('PROTEIN')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-blue\">98%</div></div><br><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-name\">Potassium</div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrient-value\">846mg</div><div style=\"display:inline-block;width: -moz-calc(100% - 189px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 189px);width: -o-calc(100% - 189px);width: calc(100% - 189px);\"><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-blue\" style=\"width:24.17%\" onmouseover=\"spoonacularShowNutritionComposition(event,'POTASSIUM')\" onmouseout=\"spoonacularHideNutritionComposition('POTASSIUM')\"></div><div class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar-number spoonacular-blue\">24%</div></div><br><div style=\"margin-top:12px;width:12px;height:12px\" class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-salmon\"></div><div style=\"margin-left:6px;margin-right:6px;width:12px;height:12px\" class=\"spoonacular-nutrition-visualization-bar spoonacular-blue\"></div>covered percent of daily need";

    // doc.LoadXml(response.Body); // Here is the error (The first is : itemtype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 1, position 37)
    doc.LoadXml(XamlString);

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
}
```

I used the **Unirest-API** library for RapidApi e **Newtonsoft.Json** library for serialize Xml.

I have to get a valid Json string. Is something wrong with the API's request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659155/2486496) to a very similar question.  Are your fields coming back with spaces in them similarly?

Comment: Also, could you provide a copy of the actual response back from the request, so we can see what may be up with the format of the response?

Comment: I updated with the string returned by the API.

Comment: Is html the responce?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your XML string.

Using [this tool](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson) return this Json:

```
{
  "html": {
    "body": {
      "parsererror": {
        "-style": "display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black",
        "h3": [
          "This page contains the following errors:",
          "Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."
        ],
        "div": {
          "-style": "font-family:monospace;font-size:12px",
          "#text": "error on line 1 at column 15: AttValue: \" or ' expected
"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So check if your xml string is valid with that tool before you hardcode it in the code.